# What html/css attributes are mail safe?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, gmail

I have recently been developing a newsletter for a client of mine. How ever I can't seem to find good information on what css and html are safe to use in the major mail clients.

I thought that maybe there are people here that have the knowledge and we can create some sort of list of things that work in major mail clients.

This is a list of popular mail clients I borrowed from campaign monitor. (If I forgot somthing please tell me)

```
Microsoft Outlook
Apple Mail
Hotmail
Yahoo! Mail
Gmail
```

The question is what tags, attributes, special quirks are there in these major browsers and how can they be easily avoided.

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of posts to get you started:

http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/

Comment: First one is strongly outdated now ;) https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ <-- is a little better

Answer (score 10):

There is a detailed and comprehensive list of CSS support in common mail clients at Campaign Monitor.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 7):

You can find a comprehensive list of supported and non-supported CSS features for all major email clients at [**Email Standard Project**](http://www.email-standards.org/)

A really useful bootstrap for developing HTML emails, which has a ton of discrepancy eliminators is [**HTML Email Bolerplate**](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/)

And as a general rule - always use tables and all the old-school HTML tags ( `align`, `center`, `valign`, `color` etc. ). Some [reading](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an email css cheat-sheet. http://intenseminimalism.com/2010/email-css-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

PDF providing table format for CSS Support in different mail clients:
Gives information for Web Clients, Desktop Clients on Different OS and Mobile Mail Clients.

[CSS support by Different Email Clients](https://i3.campaignmonitor.com/assets/files/css/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-may-2014.pdf?ver=5320&_ga=1.228308635.745708791.1442556968)

https://i3.campaignmonitor.com/assets/files/css/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-may-2014.pdf?ver=5320&_ga=1.228308635.745708791.1442556968

Answer (score 0):

Gmail already supports the `style` tag in the head

> You can use a subset of CSS selectors to apply styles. Gmail supports
>   class, element, and id selectors.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>This text is blue.</p=>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And media queries:

> You can use standard CSS media queries to adjust the styling of an email to suit the user's current device. Gmail supports queries against the screen width, orientation, and resolution.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>
        This text is blue if the window width is
        below 500px and red otherwise.
      </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```