# Style a mail send using smtp.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating website to take booking of my travel agency. I have only few packages and I am collecting the documents in firebase. Whenever someone books a trip a confirmation email is send to the client using a simple smtp.js. I am using the code given to do so.

```
  Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    Username: "trippyadive.web.app@gmail.com",
    Password: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    To: email,
    From: "trippyadive.web.app@gmail.com",
    Subject: "Sending Email using javascript",
    Body: `Your package of ${packageFields} for ${name} with total ${persons} persons (incl. ${name}) dated ${date} has been provisonalised. Your seat will be confirmed once you complete the payment of the Security Deposit`,
  })
```

I would like to add some style to the email sent, i.e. in the `Body`. Especially make a table and add some css.

Is there any way to do so? If yes please explain the method.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12921772/1575157) before trying HTML email.

I can't find any reference to HTML emailing in the smtp.js documentation, BUT it doesn't harm to try it. I would do something like this just to know if html is propagated as is:

```js
  Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    Username: "trippyadive.web.app@gmail.com",
    Password: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    To: email,
    From: "trippyadive.web.app@gmail.com",
    Subject: "Sending Email using javascript",
    Body: `<strong>Your package</strong> of ${packageFields} for ${name} with total ${persons} persons (incl. ${name}) dated ${date} has been provisonalised. Your seat will be confirmed once you complete the payment of the Security Deposit`,
  })
```